# How do I block specific contact groups on an Android Note? On the weekend I don't want to be bothered by the 101 people taged in "workgroup"

Tags: contact-groups

How do I block specific contact groups on a Note 10 lite (Android version 10, UI 2.5)? On the weekend I don't want to be bothered by the 101 people taged in "Workgroup".

Basically, I don't want to be contacted on the weekend by "Workgroup",and still yet, receive texts and calls from outside of the blocked group (I want the ability to temporarily silence whole "groups" on my Android Note).

Comment: Could you [edit] and mention the specific device model and its Android version, possibly from Settings - About device (or similar menu)? We're not sure what model "Android Note" is.

Comment: Yes, thank you.